# Use variables in gather function

Tags: r, database, tidyr

I am using R to transform a datatable form wide to long format. It works, except that the have to use a Variable for the new column:

```
library(readr)
library(tidyr)

files <- Sys.glob("sources/*.csv") #data is from http://api.worldbank.org/v2/en/indicator/NY.GDP.MKTP.CD?downloadformat=csv , the worldbank data for current GDP
data_wide <- read_csv(files, skip = 4)
ind <- as.character(data_wide[1,3])
data_wide <- data_wide[, !(colnames(data_wide) %in% c("X63", "Indicator Code", "Indicator Name"))]

data <- gather(data_wide, "year", value = ind, "1960":"2017")
```

So ind is a variable with my indicator name. In the final datatable data the value column is called ind instead of the value of the variable ind. I need it variable, because ultimatly i want to apply this code as a formula on a list of datasets from the sources folder (right now there is only one). Does anybody know an answer or workaround?

Comment: Please add a reproducible example, so folks can help you by running the code.

Comment: What is `test`?  Is it a string or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the bad question, I hope now it is more understandable. Also, I solved the problem using "melt" form the "reshape2" package instead of gather:

```
data <- melt(data_wide, id.vars = c("Country Name", "Country Code"), variable.name = "year", value.name=ind)
```

I still don't know why gather cannot use variables as names...

Answer (score 0):

Use `!!as.character(ind)`:

```r
data <- gather(data_wide, "year", value = !!as.character(ind), "1960":"2017")
```